# Validate properties before upload accept

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Community.
I'm playing with WebAPI. 
Trying to accomplish:

- WebAPI service method that accepts large file + set of metadata for it. 
  Using multipart form data to pass this along.
- .NET app client that is sending pointed multipart data to the server side. That data includes metadata + large file itself.

I'd like to have server validate metadata of that file and only then continue accepting file upload. If metadata is incorrect or same metadata file is uploading - decline to avoid not needed load.

My question is - can this be achieved via one call? Or I'll have to work with kind of transaction requests - one for metadata & second for file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can keep it simple just validating the metadata before starting the upload from the client.

For example, you can perform a first POST request to some resource that validates the metadata and, if it returns OK, then you start to upload the file and you send the metadata along with the file upload request.